# Pack correctly arrays of elements on JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jtextfield, form-layout

I have simple form, and two Arrays, JLabels and JTextFeilds:

```
ArrayList<JLabel> jlabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
ArrayList<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();
```

I wand to add it to Frame and pack this elements correctly **(please see image)**.
[image]

Please look at a piece of my code:

```
public class ProductForm extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane; 

public ProductForm() {

    initComponents();
    actions();      
}

public void actions() {
    setTitle("Product selection");

    setSize(600, 350);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

private void initComponents() {
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    ArrayList<JLabel> jlabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    ArrayList<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

    //for (int a = 0; a < product.list.size(); a++) {
    for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {  // let say 7 for example
    jlabels.add(new javax.swing.JLabel()); 
    textFields.add(new javax.swing.JTextField());       
        for (JLabel j:jlabels) {
            contentPane.add(j);
        }
        for (JTextField f:textFields) {
            contentPane.add(f);
        }
    }             

    pack();
}
```

As a result, I have this content: **please see image below**
[image]

Please help me how to pack this elements correctly.
Should I initialize it in some way?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: use  a `GridLayout` or `GridBagLayout` to get the required format.

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera, I have no idea where should I add a layout.
I mean in which place of a code? Can you advice smth. please

Comment: In your constructor call `setLayout(new GridLayout(-))`.

Comment: @Satya, thank you. Will try it

Comment: @EvgEvg I have posted answer to make you understand. I have forgot to add a comment regarding the same

Comment: @Pragnani Kinnera, Grid Layout is broad my elements all over the form. It's too huge inputs there.
Could you please advice another layout which is close to my first Screen in Post above?

Comment: The original code would have worked better if some sizing hints had been provided for the text fields. So `textFields.add(new javax.swing.JTextField());` would better have been `textFields.add(new javax.swing.JTextField(10)); //adjust col # to suit need`

Comment: @EvgEvg Check my update

Comment: This is awesome new things I've learnt due to your answers guys.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
private void initComponents() {
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(7, 2)); // 7 rows and 2 cols
            setContentPane(contentPane);

            ArrayList<JLabel> jlabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
            ArrayList<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

            // for (int a = 0; a < product.list.size(); a++) {
            for (int a = 0; a < 7.; a++) { // let say 7 for example
                JLabel jLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel("New Label");
                jlabels.add(jLabel);
                JTextField jTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
                textFields.add(jTextField);
                contentPane.add(jLabel);
                contentPane.add(jTextField);
            }

            pack();
        }
```

### Update

```
private void initComponents() {
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout()); // 7 rows and 2 cols
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
        constraints.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST;
        constraints.weightx=0.5;
        constraints.weighty=0.5;


        ArrayList<JLabel> jlabels = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
        ArrayList<JTextField> textFields = new ArrayList<JTextField>();

        // for (int a = 0; a < product.list.size(); a++) {
        for (int a = 0; a < 7.; a++) { // let say 7 for example
            JLabel jLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel("New Label");
            constraints.gridx=0;
            constraints.gridy=a;
            jlabels.add(jLabel);
            JTextField jTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField(10);
            textFields.add(jTextField);
            contentPane.add(jLabel, constraints);
            constraints.gridx=1;
            contentPane.add(jTextField, constraints);
        }

        pack();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You should use a proper **layout**. I suggest using a `GridLayout`.

Add this line in your `initComponents()` method:

```
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2)); // 7 rows, 2 columns
```

And change you loop to the following:

```
for (int a = 0; a < 7; a++) {
    jlabels.add(new javax.swing.JLabel()); 
    textFields.add(new javax.swing.JTextField());
}             

for (int i=0; i<7; i++) {
    contentPane.add(jlabels.get(i));
    contentPane.add(textFields.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Hackerdarshi